# Set a UIView width twice another view using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, autolayout

In my screen I have two view that are horizontally near to each other. I want the width of first view be twice of the width of second view.

I man for example, if **right view has width=200** the **second one show by with=100**.

As I search and look in auto-layout, it has options for alignments and spaces between views. Do it has option for defining such relationships too?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this programmatically by adding manual constraints that work with autolayout. I'm sure using InterfaceBuilder is also an option.

```
UIView *firstView;
UIView *secondView;
[firstView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:firstView
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       multiplier:2.0
                                                         constant:0]];
```

Note the multiplier there is **2.0** which is where it forces the width to be double.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, Is it possible to add it with xib too?

Comment: I haven't used xibs myself, but I don't see why not. Sorry I can't be more help in that case.